# MongoDB C# - How to use $push with $position and $each?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/), I know I can use the $push command together with $each and $position modifiers to add en element at the **start of an array**.

How can I create this command with the MonogoDB C# Driver?

To be more clear, I want to perform this query (taken from the official docs):

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
        scores: {
           $each: [ 50, 60, 70 ],
           $position: 0
        }
     }
   }
)
```

Comment: You may want to add the exact MongoDB query you're trying to map to the C# driver.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var filter= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(c=>c._Id,1);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.PushEach(c=>c.scores,[50,60,70],position:0);
client.GetDatabase(YourMongoDB).GetCollection<BsonDocument>(YourMongoCollection).UpdateOne(filter, update);
```